# Shannon diversity index in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, spatial-index

As my data sets are very large I’ve been unable to compute anything in R. I’ve been successful doing things manually in ArcGIS Pro.

Now I’m attempting to calculate the Shannon diversity index for every point in my raster.

Is there a tool in ArcGIS Pro to do this?

I know it should be doable in R but as I mentioned large data sets seem to make that impossible.

I tried Diversity Tools, a user written add on but couldn’t get it to install or show up in the latest version of ArcGIS Pro.

My data set is very large. Dimensions : 96523, 153811, 14846299153  (nrow, ncol, ncell) and cell represents 30mx30m. On disk (when compressed) it takes up 500MB or so of space, but its too large (R says it would need 100GB of free RAM) to be read into memory, so perhaps all the repeated reading/writing to disk is what slows it down.

As background, I am following this code: https://github.com/AramburuMerlos/cropdiv_usa/blob/master/07_GammaDiversity.R

Even with the lowest rectangle width (2 cells), it has computed for 3 hours now and the resulting output that is being built is only 40MB. Since final size will probably be 500MB or more, this means at least30 hours for width of 2. Since I eventually want much larger widths for diversity calculation, this is crazy.

My computer is pretty decent, CPU = 5600X, 32GB RAM, SSD..

Comment: Could you please describe your dataset? What errors are you getting in R to make you think your dataset is too large? What are your computer's system specs?

Comment: I have edited. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you also wish to ask about your R code then please do that in a separate question, and include a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried and where you are stuck.  For code review there is the [codereview.se] Stack Exchange.